# "About This Computer" and System Settings/Details do not open

Tags: 13.04

When I try to view the Systems Settings / details or click the "About This Computer" on menu bar, nothing happens. Nothing loads, nothing in process list. Its a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04, built in a VirtualBox.

Any help? Thank you

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and, at this point, it appears that can only be solved by disabling 3D acceleration in VistualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Guest Additions in the VirtualBox VM? You should have that option when the VM is running, the Devices menu should allow you the option of installing the Guest Additions from its ISO. That should prove beneficial to the Guest VM. Have found that a requirement if you want proper behaviour from the machine.